# Canon 60D shutter speed problem

Tags: shutter-speed, canon-60d

I have a Canon 60D EOS. I can not change the shutter speed higher than 1/250. I updated the firmware to 1.1.1 but nothing changed. Also I updated the Magic Lantern firmware but still I see the same problem. How can I fix this?

Is it related to my camera or lens?

Comment: Are you by chance using a flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the 60D's flash sync speed. When you have a flash connected you can not get a shorter shutter speed than that without enabling high speed sync. That is because of the way the shutter works - even at a 1/8000 shutter speed, the shutter "rolls" across the image, taking about 1/250 second.  Each individual part is only exposed for your 1/8000 but it takes that time to roll across the image. When you use flash, the exposure has to have the whole frame being exposed at the same instant, and that's only possible at a speed longer than what it takes the shutter to roll the image.

If you don't have a flash, the camera surely thinks you do, and something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1/250 is generally the shutterspeed when connected to a flash. Disconnect and your shutterspeed should be changeable up to 1/8000.